# SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#0.resizer' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, dom

Im trying to execute a `querySelectorAll` on my webpage using javascript, but when I try to get it by using the div id as parameter of search, it gets this error:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '#0.resizer' is not a valid selector.

I'm using HTML5 and ReactJS, what could be the problem?

Here is the line of code:

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + ".resizer"));
```

Solutions?

Comment: @gforce301 Flagged. That is literally their question: "how do you fix the syntax error and why is it happening"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to tell what could be the issue but as i can assume currently on the basis of your selector. The generated markup should look like:

```
<div id="0" class="resizer">...</div>
```

But if it is like:

```
<div id="0.resizer">...</div>
```

Then you should escape the `.` as it has special meaning in css. It denotes class selector. So you should escape it like:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("#" + id + "\.resizer")
 //document.querySelectorAll(`#${id}\.resizer`) // <---es6 template variable
```

Comment: Thanks, that clarify my mind, the problem was my way of thinking about the generated markup.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here is that id selector `#` can't start with a number. You must escape it:

```js
test( '#1.foo' ); // fail
test( '#' + CSS.escape('1') + '.foo' ); // works
test( '#\\31.foo' ); // works


function test( selector ) {
  let pass = false;
  try {
    const elem = document.querySelector( selector );
    pass = elem.textContent === "hi";
  } catch(e) {
    pass = false;
  }
  console.log( selector, pass );
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="foo">hi</div>
```